# Nested strong parameters in rails - AssociationTypeMismatch MYMODEL expected, got ActionController::Parameters()

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I'm rendering a model and it's children Books in JSON like so:

```
{"id":2,"complete":false,"private":false, "books" [{ "id":2,"name":"Some Book"},.....
```

I then come to update this model by passing the same JSON back to my controller and I get the following error:

ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Book (#2245089560) expected, got ActionController::Parameters(#2153445460))

In my controller I'm using the following to update:

```
@project.update_attributes!(project_params)

private

def project_params
    params.permit(:id, { books: [:id] } )
end
```

No matter which attributes I whitelist in `permit` I can't seem to save the child model.

Am I missing something obvious?

**Update - another example:**

Controller:

```
def create
    @model = Model.new(model_params)
end
def model_params
    params.fetch(:model, {}).permit(:child_model => [:name, :other])
end
```

Request:

```
post 'api.address/model', :model => { :child_model => { :name => "some name" } }
```

Model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :child_model
```

Error:

expected ChildModel, got ActionController::Parameters

Tried this method to no avail: http://www.rubyexperiments.com/using-strong-parameters-with-nested-forms/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm using Angular.js & Rails & Rails serializer, and this worked for me:

**Model**:

- has_many :features
- accepts_nested_attributes_for :features

**ModelSerializer**:

- has_many :features, root: :features_attributes

**Controller**:

- params.permit features_attributes: [:id, :enabled]

**AngularJS**:

- ng-repeat="feature in model.features_attributes track by feature.id

Comment: What is ModelSerializer?

Comment: @jerzy I imagine he's probably talking about [this](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers).

Answer (score 13):

Are you using `accepts_nested_attributes_for :books` on your project model? If so, instead of `"books"`, the key should be `"books_attributes"`.

```
def project_params
  params.permit(:id, :complete, :false, :private, books_attributes: [:id, :name])
end
```

Comment: Thanks Josh - I'm using accepts_nested_attributes_for :books but I'm not using a nested form when updating the objects, I'm using the json output. When I change the key to: books_attributes it doesn't seem to update the books and specifies books as an unpermitted parameter.

Comment: @AlanH, you need to edit your form, like this: `f.fields_for :book, book do |b|`

Comment: Thanks @fl00r but I'm passing the data via AngularJS and don't have a form.

Comment: @AlanH Did you ever find a solution for this?  I'm facing the exact same issue.

Comment: @Duane - No I ended up posting the models separately as I couldn't find a good solution. I've updated the question with another example.

Comment: @Duane - try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584142/rails-4-strong-params-has-many-with-json?rq=1

Answer (score 7):

My solution to this using ember.js was setting the books_attributes mannualy.

In controller:

```
def project_params      
  params[:project][:books_attributes] = params[:project][:books_or_whatever_name_relationships_have] if params[:project][:books_or_whatever_name_relationships_have]
  params.require(:project).permit(:attr1, :attr2,...., books_attributes: [:book_attr1, :book_attr2, ....])

end
```

So rails checks and filters the nested attributes as it expected them to come

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. My parent model was an `Artist` and the child model was a `Url`.

```rb
class ArtistsController < ApplicationController

  def update
    artist = Artist.find(params[:id].to_i)
    artist.update_attributes(artist_params)
    render json: artist
  end

private

  def artist_params
    remap_urls(params.permit(:name, :description, urls: [:id, :url, :title, :_destroy]))
  end

  def remap_urls(hash)
    urls = hash[:urls]
    return hash unless urls
    hash.reject{|k,v| k == 'urls' }.merge(:urls_attributes => urls)
  end
end

class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :urls, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :urls, allow_destroy: true
end

class Url < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :artist
end
```

... and in coffeescript (to handle deletions):

```
  @ArtistCtrl = ($scope, $routeParams, $location, API) ->

    $scope.destroyUrls = []

    $scope.update = (artist) ->
      artist.urls.push({id: id, _destroy: true}) for id in $scope.destroyUrls
      artist.$update(redirectToShow, artistError)

    $scope.deleteURL = (artist,url) ->
      artist.urls.splice(artist.urls.indexOf(url),1)
      $scope.destroyUrls.push(url.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something is missing from all of the answers, which is the inputs for `fields_for` in the form.

The *form* works if you do this:

```
f.fields_for @model.submodel do ..
```

However, the form is sent as `model[submodel]`, but that's what causes the error others have mentioned in their answers. If you try to do `model.update(model_params)`, Rails will raise an error that it's expecting a `Submodel` type.

To fix this, make sure you follow the `:name, value` format:

```
f.fields_for :submodel, @model.submodel do ...
```

Then in the controller, make sure you put `_attributes` on your params:

```
def model_params
  params.require(:model).permit(submodel_attributes: [:field])
end
```

Now the save, update, etc. will work fine.

Answer (score -3):

Wasted several days trying to figure out how to use accepts_nested_attributes with Angular, and the issue is always the same: Rails whitelist will not allow the variables into the params hash.  I've tried every single different whitelisting syntax that everyone said on SO and other blogs, tried using :inverse, tried using habtm and mas_many_through, tried manually rolling my own solution but that wont work if the whitelist wont allow params through, tried doing what http://guides.rubyonrails.org says about 'Outside the Scope of Strong Parameters', tried removing whitelisting all together which isnt really an option but it causes other problems anyways. Not sure why rails 4 strong parameter whitelisting wont allow arbitrary data thru, thats a huge problem especially if accepts_nested_attributes doesn't work either....  I guess we are left to just create/delete all associations on a separate page/form/controller and look like an idiot making my end users use several forms/pages to do something that should be easily doable on 1 page with 1 form.  Ya know, usually I expect Angular to screw me, but this time Angular worked quite well and it was actually Rails 4 that screwed me twice on 1 issue that should be very straightforward.

Comment: This is not really answering the question directly. Can you edit your post so it directly answers the question posted?

Comment: I agree with the last comment but I sympathize with this response since it appears the accepted answer doesn't work as of Rails 4.2.0. I've gone through a similar circus of scouring the internet for an solution and trying every available permit pattern. I've had luck setting up a separate json array which accepts the model object's attributes which I parse out and then manually set active record associations for but this makes both client and server side code super ugly.